# Python module not callable

Tags: python, module

I searched many posts, but they don't seem to be helpful.

In folder dir1/ I have main.py and plotcluster.py. In plotcluster.py I have:

```
import matplotlib as plt
import itertools as it
....
def plotc():
    colors = it.cycle('ybmgk')
    ....
    plt.figure()
    ....
```

In main.py, I use plotcluster.py:

```
import plotcluster as plc
....
plc.plotc()
```

But this gives me a error saying module object is not callable.

```
     20     linestyles = it.cycle('-:_')
     21
---> 22     plt.figure()
     23     # plot the most frequent ones first
     24     for iter_count, (i, _) in enumerate(Counter(centerid).most_common()):

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

It doesn't complaint about the itertools module, but the plt one bothers it. This makes me so confusing!

any help will be appreciated !! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
plt.figure.Figure()
```

not

```
plt.figure
```

Comment: couldn't believe I spent 2hours on this stupid mistake!! I had it right in another code....Thanks so much for point it out!

Answer (score 8):

@suhail 's answer will work. Essentially you were accessing matplotlib.figure which is the module. Also I think you are trying to access the pyplot functions (gen that is imported as plt) and its enough to import that module to access most of the standard plotting api's.

So in your `plotcluster.py` change the first line to

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

It should be smooth sailing from there on and you can use stuff like

`plt.plot()`, `plt.show()` and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the additional comment, you're right that I was trying to use matplotlib.pyplot() , just totally missed it. THanks